# Creating separate dictionaries with a list of values in it

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures, key-value

I have a dictionary like this :

```
d = {
    'hosts': [
        {'hostname': 'abc', 'ip': '127.0.0.1', 'extra_check_cmd': 'check-me'},
        {'hostname': 'def', 'ip': '127.0.0.2', 'extra_check_cmd': 'check-it,check-this'},
        {'hostname': 'ijk,uvw,xyz', 'ip': '127.0.0.3,127.0.0.4,127.0.0.5', 'extra': 'check-me,check-this,check-it'}
    ]
}
```

I want to create the following dictionary out of it

```
d = {
    'hosts': [
        {'hostname': 'abc', 'ip': '127.0.0.1', 'extra_check_cmd': 'check-me'},
        {'hostname': 'def', 'ip': '127.0.0.2', 'extra_check_cmd': 'check-it'},
        {'hostname': 'def', 'ip': '127.0.0.2', 'extra_check_cmd': 'check-this'},
        {'hostname': 'ijk', 'ip': '127.0.0.3', 'extra': 'check-me'},
        {'hostname': 'uvw', 'ip': '127.0.0.4', 'extra': 'check-me'},
        {'hostname': 'xyz', 'ip': '127.0.0.5', 'extra': 'check-me'}
        {'hostname': 'ijk', 'ip': '127.0.0.3', 'extra': 'check-it'},
        {'hostname': 'uvw', 'ip': '127.0.0.4', 'extra': 'check-it'},
        {'hostname': 'xyz', 'ip': '127.0.0.5', 'extra': 'check-it'}
        {'hostname': 'ijk', 'ip': '127.0.0.3', 'extra': 'check-this'},
        {'hostname': 'uvw', 'ip': '127.0.0.4', 'extra': 'check-this'},
        {'hostname': 'xyz', 'ip': '127.0.0.5', 'extra': 'check-this'}
    ]
}
```

That means each list of values should have a separate sub-dictionaries wherever list of values are given.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```py
def expand_dict(host):
    # Create all of the possible key-value pairs for each key in the original dictionary
    kv_pairs = [[(k, v) for v in vals.split(",")] for k, vals in host.items()]
    # Find the number of dictionaries this would expand to
    max_len = max(len(p) for p in kv_pairs)
    # A list of possible values must either be the length of the number of dictionaries we expect, or length 1 so we can repeat the value max_len times
    assert all(len(pairs) in {1, max_len} for pairs in kv_pairs)
    # Expand all of the length 1 value lists to length max_len
    updated_pairs = [p if len(p) == max_len else p * max_len for p in kv_pairs]
    # Return a generator of dictionaries for each of the sets of key-value pairs
    return (dict(pairs) for pairs in zip(*updated_pairs))

input_dict = {'hosts': [{'hostname': 'abc', 'ip': '127.0.0.1', 'extra_check_cmd': 'check-me'}, {'hostname': 'def', 'ip': '127.0.0.2', 'extra_check_cmd': 'check-it,check-this'}, {'hostname': 'ijk,uvw,xyz', 'ip': '127.0.0.3,127.0.0.4,127.0.0.5', 'extra': 'check-me'}]}
output_dict = {'hosts': [d for host in input_dict['hosts'] for d in expand_dict(host)]}
```

Breaking it down further, lets try it on an example. In this case, I'm using `host = d['hosts'][2]`.

```py
{'hostname': 'ijk,uvw,xyz',
 'ip': '127.0.0.3,127.0.0.4,127.0.0.5',
 'extra': 'check-me'}
```

The line `kv_pairs = [[(k, v) for v in vals.split(",")] for k, vals in host.items()]` gives us list of possible key-value pairs for the inner list of items.

```py
[
    [('hostname', 'ijk'), ('hostname', 'uvw'), ('hostname', 'xyz')],
    [('ip', '127.0.0.3'), ('ip', '127.0.0.4'), ('ip', '127.0.0.5')],
    [('extra', 'check-me')],
]
```

As you can see, there are 3 key-value pairs each for the `"hostname"` and `"ip"` keys, and only 1 pair for the `"extra"` key in the original host dictionary. The goal is to produce 3 dictionaries with `'extra': 'check-me'` in each of them. So, we want to find the number of dictionaries we expect to produce.

The line `max_len = max(len(p) for p in kv_pairs)` gives us 3. Then, just as a sanity check, we want to make sure that every set of key-value pairs in `kv_pairs` is either length 1 or length 3. If it were anything else, the problem would not be well defined, so we add the assert `assert all(len(pairs) in {1, max_len} for pairs in kv_pairs)`.

We then expand all of the length 1 kv pair lists to length 3 by repeating them. This list comprehension basically takes all of the length 3 lists and repeats the length 1 lists 3 times each so they're all the same length.

```py
updated_pairs = [p if len(p) == max_len else p * max_len for p in kv_pairs]

[[('hostname', 'ijk'), ('hostname', 'uvw'), ('hostname', 'xyz')],
 [('ip', '127.0.0.3'), ('ip', '127.0.0.4'), ('ip', '127.0.0.5')],
 [('extra', 'check-me'), ('extra', 'check-me'), ('extra', 'check-me')]]
```

Now that everything is nice and lined up, we can start creating dictionaries. We can use `zip()` for this, which gives us iterators of tuples with items from each of the input iterators we pass in. I'm using Python's unpacking syntax to expand each list inside `updated_kv_pairs` as a separate argument to `zip()`. In other words,

```py
zip(*updated_kv_pairs)
```

is the same as

```py
zip(updated_kv_pairs[0], updated_kv_pairs[1], updated_kv_pairs[2])
```

Each iteration of `zip()` gives us the list of key-value pairs that go inside of a single dictionary we output. This gives us

```py
{'hostname': 'ijk', 'ip': '127.0.0.3', 'extra': 'check-me'}
{'hostname': 'uvw', 'ip': '127.0.0.4', 'extra': 'check-me'}
{'hostname': 'xyz', 'ip': '127.0.0.5', 'extra': 'check-me'}
```

Comment: Yes I am not using dict anywhere in my code its just for the explanation here. Thanks alot man I really appreciate your timely response.

Comment: @HardySandhu Weeeeell did you try it? ;-)

Comment: @rchome The code in this answer is great, but a textual explanation alongside it would be even better!

Comment: I am also not able to understand it via https://pythontutor.com/ also. A little explanation would be better.

Comment: I've updated the code with some comments. Let me know if there's anything needs more clarity.

Comment: Can you make the above code without using functional programming or in other words just a straight forward python code ? If possible? @rchome